# is there a simple way to know your mouse coordinates in 3D world space while hovering?

Tags: coordinates, 3d-cursor, mouse

I'm wondering if there is a way to know your mouse coordinates while hovering. Without having to query the position of the  3D cursor?

For example to show what I mean, see below image of another software. As you move your mouse around, the coordinates dynamically update (in red box) to show where your mouse is currently located.

[image: example]

Is this a thing in Blender?

I came across this post:

[similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76464/how-to-get-the-mouse-coordinates-in-3space-relative-to-the-local-coordinates-of)

which sort of does the same thing but seems like a bit of a mission for something that I would think should be a built-in feature as it is in a lot of modelling software?

Please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Your given link solves the problem, there is no build-in solution. Why would you expect that? What is the use case for such a feature?

Comment: Yes I know, but thought maybe since 2.8 came out there was a built-in option to have this displayed somewhere. I would expect that because it's a common feature in alot of modelling software I've used. The specific use case I had in mind would but if you imported an object in Blender and didn't know it's coordinates and it ends up off way somewhere, you could zoom to it and just hover the mouse to know where it is and potentially move it somewhere else where your scene is. Is there any east way to achieve that?